# Apache Hive standalone metastore 4.0.0-beta-1 not working with older or Latest MariaDB versions

Tags: hive, hive-metastore

I am able to get Hive 4.0.0-beta-1 standalone metastore with mysql:latest & Postgres:latest from docker hub working without any issues, however whenever I use mariadb:latest or any older version it throws the below error.

**Error**: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL' at line 1 (state=42000,code=1064)
Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent!
underlying cause: java.io.IOException : Schema script failed, errorcode 2

I've tried possible old versions of maria DB - just doesnt work. Looks like the developers of Apache Hive need to update their MY SQL scripts.

I am using a docker environment with a docker compose file.